# How to create a hotkey to connect to a specific bluetooth device (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I have a question that's been surprisingly difficult to find answers for, and the answers that I have found were either not what I wanted, or far more complicated than they were worth.

So. What I want to do is basically to be able to make a keybind that connects to a specific device (AKA my bluetooth earbuds). For a while, I was making do with just using `win+k` to open the Connect Menu and then click my device, but I kept accidentally connecting to devices of my neighbors because the list shuffles around so much when new devices are detected. I started digging and found [Bluetooth Command Line Tools](https://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools), which would (at least hypothetically) allow me to have a batch script that connected to my device. I got that set-up, then ran into the issue that the cmd window opened up every time I ran it, fixed that by running it through a vbs script I found to hide the cmd window. Then, I tried binding it to a key by creating a shortcut and that only sometimes worked. And now here we are.

There just has to be a better way than just stitching all this stuff together. I saw people mention AutoHotkey, but I've never used it before so I didn't feel like diving in head first like that without having a clear goal.

Comment: When you say it only sometimes worked, can you please explain? What are the symptoms? When does it work, when does it not?

Comment: If the script works for you and it's just about launching it reliably with a shortcut. AutoHotKey would certainly be the best solution. It should take fewer than 10 lines of AHK script. Let me know if you need a hand with AHK.

Comment: @music2myear It would only trigger the batch script like every 3 times I pressed the keybind. I have no idea why.

Comment: @Aniket That sounds surprisingly easy. I'll look into it and let you know if I have an issue.